# Right association between three models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I am struggling to find the easiest solution for associating three models:

1. User
2. Organization
3. Role

User and Organization is a HABTM association - one user can have multiple organizations and vice versa.

One user can also have multiple roles, but just one per organization.

Right now I have this in my model:

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles, through: :organizations
  has_and_belongs_to_many :organizations, :join_table => :organizations_users
end
```

**organization.rb**

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => :organizations_users
  has_many :roles
end
```

**role.rb**

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, through: :organizations
  belongs_to :organizations
end
```

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my though:

- Given that you're using the `has_and_belongs_to_many` and given Rails' defaults, your specification of the `join_table` is redundant
- Your `has_many :roles, through: :organizations` will only work if you have both a `role` and a `user` field in the `organizations` tables, as Rails will expect to do a SQL `select` of that table looking for those fields.

Since you want users to have up to one one role per organization, then I would think the most straightforward thing would be to add a `role` field to the `organizations_users` model, as follows:

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles, through: :organizations_users
  has_many :organizations, :through => :organizations_users
  has_many :organizations_users
end
```

**organization.rb**

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, :through => :organizations_users
  has_many :roles, :through => :organizations_users
  has_many :organizations_users
end
```

**organization_user.rb**

```
class OrganizationUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :organization
  belongs_to :role
end
```

**role.rb**

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

The above assumes that you have some reason to want `Role` to continue to be an `ActiveModel` as opposed to just a string field in the `organizations_users` table.

Comment: Perfect, that works like a charm! Just one issue - when I populate the db with seed data, the organizations_users table which has now 4 colums (id, user_id, organization_id, role_id) creates separate entries for every association e.g. _user 1 - organization 1_ and _user 1 - role 1_ instead of _user 1 - organization 1 - role 1_ . Any suggestion how I could fix that?

Comment: How are you creating the entries? That will happen if you ever assign through a `has_many` helper method _other_ than the one for `organizations_users`, since the other helper methods only know about an association between two elements.

Comment: That makes sense... Right now I am trying to create a new user with this code in the console: `OrganizationUserRole#create_user(email: 'thomas@aquarterit.com', password: 'password')` (Instead of user OrganizationUser I am now using the model OrganizationUserRole. Should have picked something shorter... anyway). The result is `=> OrganizationUserRole(id: integer, user_id: integer, organization_id: integer, role_id: integer)` - I'm still doing something wrong but I just don't know what

Comment: See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference for a description of the `create_association` method (i.e. `create_user` in your case). It should create a new user instance and set the value of `user_id` in the object you called the `create_user` method on. However, `#` is a comment character in Ruby, so everything after that is being ignored in the Rails console, so you're just getting a printout of the OrganizationUserRole constant.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer pointed me in the right direction. I followed the instructions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771503/how-to-join-mutli-role-multi-organisation-tables-in-rails and it worked like a charm.