# Rails ActiveRecord: Three Table has_many through: associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

I am attempting to build a table to handle both the location and category a certain campaign has been set to with the following model associations:

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :campaign_category_metro_bids, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :metros,     through: :campaign_category_metro_bids
    has_many :categories, through: :campaign_category_metro_bids

end

class Metro < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :campaign_category_metro_bids
    has_many :campaigns,  through: :campaign_category_metro_bids
    has_many :categories, through: :campaign_category_metro_bids

end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :campaign_category_metro_bids
    has_many :campaigns,  through: :campaign_category_metro_bids
    has_many :metros,     through: :campaign_category_metro_bids

end

class CampaignCategoryMetroBid < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :campaign
    belongs_to :category
    belongs_to :metro
end
```

When attempting to create a campaign for selecting two different cities and categories the result is NULL for the id of one of the paramters as:

[image]

Campaign creation code:

```
def new
    if signed_in?
        # create new campaign
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        @campaign = @user.campaigns.new
    else
        redirect_to signin_path
    end
end

def create
    @campaign = User.find(params["campaign"]["user_id"]).campaigns.build(campaign_params)

    if @campaign.save
        flash[:success] = "Campaign created!"
        redirect_to current_user
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

**UPDATED**
The view to create the campaign uses two separate collection_select for Category and Metro as:

```
        <%= f.collection_select :category_ids, Category.all, :id, :display_category, {}, {multiple: true} %>
```

and

```
    <%= f.collection_select :metro_ids, Metro.all, :id, :full_name, {}, {multiple: true} %>
```

campaigns_params:

```
    def campaign_params
        params.require(:campaign).permit(:name, :campaign_category_metro_bid_id,
                                         :metro_ids => [], :category_ids => [])
    end
```

Is there a better way to allow for the creation of a 3 table relation as I am attempting?
or a way to link the `Category` and `Metro` models at selection so that the resultant table is something like below upon campaign creation:

[image]

Comment: Can you add your campaign creation code from your controller?

Comment: @Eric Do you need anything other information?

Comment: Yeah, your campaign_params method :)

Comment: ok, I added that. Is there a way to link the selecting of `Metros` and `Category` so no NULL appears?

Comment: I would consider creating two relationship tables and populating them separately

Comment: @MichaelDurrant I need to keep them together because there is valuable information pertaining to a specific metro_id, category_id selection combination that will also be inserted into that table. Is there anything that may come to mind so that I can make this work?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to ensure data consistency across multiple tables I would begin with validations. For example:

```
class CampaignCategoryMetroBid < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :campaign
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :metro

  validates :campaign, presence: true
  validates :category, presence: true
  validates :metro, presence: true
end
```

You also might want to add this constraint to your db if that's what you need (see the migration guides). That way nobody will be able break the consistency, not even from the db cli. Now every time your code attempts to create a CampaignCategoryMetroBid instance without the foreign keys, ActiveRecord will shout and that constraints the rest of your code to "behave".

If you really just want to inject some default foreign key (or otherwise tweak the form data) you can do this while preprocessing the form data in your controller actions. For example:

```
class CampaignsController < ActionController::Base
   def create

     # Possibly refactor to a before_action
     if params[:campaign] && params[:capmaign][:metro_ids] && params[:capmaign][:metro_ids].empty?
       params[:campaign][:metro_ids] = [DEFAULT_CAMPAIGN_ID]
     end

     # Do the rest
   end
end
```

I hope this helps to generally set the direction :-)

Comment: Will this help prevent the situation that arises here:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/u4TyA.png  I want to have the permutations of `Metros` and `Category` that are selected to be in the rows, not NULL values as can be seen in the image ie. For rows with id 9,10 under `category_id` it should be listed as `1` and `2`, not NULL

Comment: I do not wish to have any default foreign key but to allow selecting as I demonstrated. What would be the addition I need?

Comment: Yes, first off, having good validations will ensure that such situation will never happen again whatever the rest of your codebase does. That will give you consistence.

Comment: Then the next step would be to create a drop-down menu in your view (select box). The user just selects one value(you should probably disable a blank value if you want to make sure something is always selected) and the value will be mapped to an id (foreign key) that will be sent in the params when he submits the form. Here I would point you to the rails guides as they explain this pretty well - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#making-select-boxes-with-ease

Comment: yes, I already have `collection_select` setup as seen in my updated post. How can I link the two, Category and Metro, together so that they populate the table as I demonstrated